# iphone - How to get friends/ids with Twitter API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

How can I get Friends/Friend's IDs of my twitter account using `Twitter API`?
In this tutorial https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone and example of, I can just *send* the updates or *send* any direct messages, but I can't *get* any direct messages or Friend's IDs or any other things that can be found from the get methods.

How can I find any data that was parsed from the get methods? (Example: `getPublicTimeline`, `getUpdate:(unsigned long)updateID`, `getDirectMessagesSinceID:`, etc..)

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=screennameofUser

Answer (score 0):

yes.You have `getFriends` method.Also You have `getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus` method.These methods will return to the following Callback,

```
   - (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
    {
//Here You can parse userInfo and get the list
    }
```